# Change UIAlertView size

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, cocos2d-iphone, uialertview

In my cocos2d game i can't change size of uialertview, i have changed statusbarorientation to landscape, and now want to init alertview with frame, and initwithframe method does not affect the size of alertview, every time the size of alert is the same, is there any way to change it ?

Comment: Depends on how exactly you want to change it. Little bit more information will improve your chance to get an useful answer. :)

Comment: I want to increase width of alert view.
UIAlerrtView* alert=[[UIAertView alloc] initwithframe:CGRectMake(200,200,200,200)];

Comment: Increasing width more problematic than the height. I'm afraid you'll need to subclass it for such purpose. I've used to do something similar but I made it fully custom(like other bg image and so one).

Comment: As i understand there is no easy way to change the size? ))

Comment: Not for Width of it... (at least I don't know it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what i did.  Create your uialertview in your controller.  then override the following class within your controller (after setting the uialertview delegate ... ie. myalertview.delegate=viewcontroller)

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    [alertView setFrame:CGRectMake(1, 20, 2700, 400)];
}
```

the frame size should change after this.

Answer (score 3):

its not possible to customized UIAlertView cause its view hierarchy is private.

its clearly mentioned here [UIAlertView_Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html)

You can go for UIView and create it similar to UIAlertView.

Answer (score 1):

Just create UIView which looks like UIAlertView. That will solve all the problem you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If a alert view has any title or messages text input within its view, then just append as many new line '\n' at the end of text it automatically scale its size.

Its just a mock, but stil doable to retain the alertbox usage in you application.