# how to increase the UIAlertView size dynamically in ipad?

Tags: ios, uialertview

Alertview code:

```
UIAlertView  *customAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"hi" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[customAlert show];
```

Comment: you can't increase the size of UIAlertView.

Comment: this may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605685/change-uialertview-size

Comment: better to create you own Control using UIView addChildeview or add subview with Animation and re-size it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't customise `UIAlertView` for example, resize, change font attributes etc, because *Apple* doesn't allow anyone to change its UI controls.

One solution is to check the subviews of `UIAlertView` and changing frame of your alert but it's against *Apple's NDA* and your app will probably get rejected by *Apple* and there will be no guaranty of solution to work in different `iOS` versions.

Other solutions is to create your own custom alert using `UIView`, `UILabel` and `UIButton` objects. But it's not recommended as it's highly unlikely that you'll provide complete functionality, controls and features provided by `UIAlertView`.