# Can I change size of UIAlertController?

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

we are using UIAlertController for message dialogs with UIAlertAction,
for example,

```
PlaneResultsDialog = UIAlertController (title: HeaderString, message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

PlaneResultsDialog.addAction (UIAlertAction (title: NSLocalizedString ("Point 1: Change", comment: "Default action"), style: .default, handler:
{
     _ in NSLog("")
    //...some code...
}))
PlaneResultsDialog.addAction (UIAlertAction (title: NSLocalizedString ("Point 2: Change", comment: "Default action"), style: .default, handler:
{
    _ in NSLog("")
    //...some code...
}))

PlaneResultsDialog.addAction (UIAlertAction (title: NSLocalizedString ("Return to Entry Screen", comment: "Default action"), style: .default, handler:
{
    _ in NSLog("")
    //...some code...
}))
    
self.present(PlaneResultsDialog, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This works, but the dialog is small and the size is defined by the system, is there any way to increase it and in general do we have va control over it?

we tried to add a view, UIView, but it did not work, crashing with this error message:
"-[UIView _actionsChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x137745780"

```
    PlaneResultsDialog = UIAlertController (title: HeaderString, message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let View = UIView()
    View.frame = CGRect (x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
    PlaneResultsDialog.view = View
    
    PlaneResultsDialog.addAction (UIAlertAction (title: NSLocalizedString ("Point 1: Change", comment: "Default action"), style: .default, handler:
    {
         _ in NSLog("")
         // ...
     }))
    PlaneResultsDialog.addAction (UIAlertAction (title: NSLocalizedString ("Point 2: Change", comment: "Default action"), style: .default, handler:
     {
         _ in NSLog("")
         //...
     }))
    PlaneResultsDialog.addAction (UIAlertAction (title: NSLocalizedString ("Point 3: Change", comment: "Default action"), style: .default, handler:
     {
         _ in NSLog("")
        //...
     }))
    
    self.present(PlaneResultsDialog, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Any other ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here [Change UIAlertView size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605685/change-uialertview-size), **its possible to change view size of UIAlertViewController**, But why do you need that if you want to customize. You may create a fully customizable alert controller for yourself. It can better.

Comment: thanks, but the thread you linked to is talking about a different class, UIAlertView, which is now deprecated (or maybe we did not understand the connection between the two, we are still new to Swift)

Comment: There is same logic in UIAlertViewController too. But i think the best solution is writing a custom AlertManager for yourself. You can customize it freely.